# How to change SwitchNavigator screen dynamically

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, redux, react-navigation

So i have a SwitchNavigator that is used within a function that receives as a prop a value(loading true or false). I want to change that function prop based on firebase onAuthStateChange so if i didn't receive a respond i render a spinner if i receive one i change the state and use it as a function but right now this is not working because componentDidMount is not waiting for a response from the firebase function! Any ideas?

```
import React from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
    import { createStackNavigator, SwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
    import MainScreen from './MainScreen';
    import AuthenticationNav from './Authentication';
    import firebase from 'firebase';
    import SplashScreen from './SplashScreen';

    export default class App extends React.Component {
      constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
          screen:'loading'
        }
      }
      componentWillMount() {
      }
      componentDidMount(){
        let isItTrue
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
            if (user) {
             isItTrue=true;
            } else {
              isItTrue=false
            }
          });
          this.setState({screen:isItTrue})
      }
      render() {console.log(this.state)
        const App=app(this.state.screen)
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
              <App />
            </View>
        );
      }
    }
    const Main = createStackNavigator({
      Main: {
        screen: MainScreen
      }
    })
    const Authentication = createStackNavigator({
      AuthenticationScreen: {
        screen: AuthenticationNav
      }
    }, {
        headerMode: 'screen'
      })
    const Splash = createStackNavigator({
      SplashScreen: {
        screen: SplashScreen
      }
    })
    const app = (isSignedIn) => {
      return SwitchNavigator({
        SignedIn: {
          screen: Main
        },
        SignedOut: {
          screen: Authentication
        },
        Loading:{
          screen:Splash
        }
      },
        {
          initialRouteName: isSignedIn==='loading' ? "Loading" : isSignedIn?"SignedIn":"SignedOut"
        }
      )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Vlad!

First, [here's a guide from react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html) that gives an example of using the SwitchNavigator. You may have already seen that.

I would move the logic to determine if is logged in to the Splash component, something like this:

```js
// SplashScreen.js
componentDidMount(){
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('SignedIn');
    } else {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('SignedOut');
    }
  });
}
```

So essentially your SwitchNavigator will always have the three screens, setting the `initialRouteName` to `"Splash"`.

Also, you'll want to use `createSwitchNavigator` instead of `SwitchNavigator` going forward.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your quick answer Brad! By passing the logic to splash you mean running the firebase function inside Splash? And in the initial route do you suggest setting the initialRouteName only to Splash?

Comment: That's right! Also, you wouldn't need to create the SwitchNavigator inside a function, it could be directly assigned to App too.

Comment: You could also handle the loading with an activity indicator... I updated to show what `componentDidMount` could look like.